# Having trouble manually adding 'Other' option in React. What gives?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a minor problem with respect to the functionality of my React Component illustrated below. Specifically, I would like for the user to be able to enter (via an input field) the poll category, if not listed under the options of the select component. This happens when the user selects the 'Other' option, which renders said input field as seen below. The issue I'm having is when the user starts entering a new category (triggering the `onChange` listener), `this.setState` results in 'category' no longer being 'Other' and, thus, the input field is no longer rendered. As such, it is impossible to enter another category. Below is the relevant code.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button, Form, Grid, Header, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class NewPoll extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    category: '',
    choice: '',
    choices: [],
  };

  onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });

  onSelect = e =>
    this.setState({
      category: e.target.value,
    });

  onAddChoice = e => {
    //...
  };

  onRemoveChoice = id => {
    //...   
  };

  onPollSubmit = e => {
    //...
  };

  render() {
    const { title, category, choices, choice } = this.state;
    const categories = [
      'Sport',
      'Travel & Tourism',
      'Education',
      'Technology',
      'Automotive',
      'Other',
    ];

    // Preview and edit poll before saving
    const shouldShowPreview = () => {
      if (title && choices.length > 0) return true;
      else return false;
    };

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Header size="large" textAlign="center">
              Create New Poll
            </Header>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Row columns={shouldShowPreview() ? 2 : 1}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Form style={styles.form} onSubmit={this.onPollSubmit}>
              <Form.Field>
                ...
              </Form.Field>

              <Form.Field
                placeholder="Category"
                label="Poll Category"
                control="select"
                value={category}
                onChange={this.onSelect}
              >
                <option disabled>Category</option>
                {categories.map((pollCategory, index) => (
                  <option value={pollCategory} key={index}>
                    {pollCategory}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </Form.Field>

              {category === 'Other' && (
                <Form.Field>
                  <label>If "Other"</label>
                  <input
                    name="category"
                    value={category}
                    placeholder="Enter category"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
              )}
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Poll Choices</label>
                <div style={styles.choice}>
                  <input
                    name="choice"
                    value={choice}
                    placeholder="Enter poll choice"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                  <Button className="add-choice" onClick={this.onAddChoice}>
                    <Icon style={styles.icon} name='add' size='large' />
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field control={Button} type="submit">
                Submit Poll
              </Form.Field>
            </Form>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

NewPoll.propTypes = {
  addNewPoll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default NewPoll;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being caused because you are using the same variable - `category` to do two things:

1. Store what the actual category is
2. Determine whether to show the additional textbox

You have two options:

1. Create a different variable to show the additional textbox. For example, something like:

   ```
   const showCategoryTextBox = ...//whether category belongs in the categories list. 
   // and then use this to control the display of the textbox.
   ```

OR

2. Modify your condition like:

   ```
   (category!== 'Sport' && category!=='Travel & Tourism' &&...)
   // include all the values in your categories list except 'Other'
   ```

Comment: Was hoping for the input field to not be displayed by default (on component render), and only be rendered when the option 'Other' is selected but I'll settle for this for now. Thanks!